# Parameter from URL not saving in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So i am creating a simple referral tracking system. A user will post the url to friends that looks something like this http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up?referral=2. That referral code is then used in a hidden input within the new users signup, but I can't seem to get it to save. I can see the value when i inspect the page, but doesnt save. Also, I used this as a guide. http://www.ytutorial.com/tutorials/2-rails-referral-affiliate-tracking

views/devise/registration/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form',
      :class => 'payola-onestep-subscription-form',
      'data-payola-base-path' => payola_path,
      'data-payola-plan-type' => resource.plan.plan_class,
      'data-payola-plan-id' => resource.plan.id}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :referral_code, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => session[:referral] } %>
```

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :capture_referal
private
def capture_referal
  session[:referral] = params[:referral] if params[:referral]
end
```

app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

```
def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :plan_id, :size, :street1, :street2, :city, :state, :zip, :referral_code)
end
```

Comment: are you using simple_form_for ?

Comment: no i updated the views for you to see.

Comment: The line `<%= f.hidden_field :referral_code, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => session[:referral] } %>` should be `<%= f.hidden_field :referral_code, value: session[:referral] %>`

Comment: the way you are making that hidden tag is the simple_form_for way of doing things except it would be 'f.input' instead of 'f.hidden_field' that is probably your issue. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form V. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field

Comment: @dhouty you knocked it out of the park. if you add it as an answer, ill vote up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for a hidden field tag using the default form builder is

```
<%= f.hidden_field :referral_code, value: session[:referral] %>
```